# No message rendered in Bean validation with @Pattern

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation

I'm making a simple form with an input field implementing Bean Validation. All of the validations work fine. The issue is the message rendered (or lack of rendering) when the user enters a non numeric value:

- If I use the @Pattern check in the Bean, no warning message is displayed in the view when the user enters a non numeric value.
- If I remove the @Pattern from the Bean, the following warning message shows up when the user enters a non numberic value:

  "j_idt8:age: 'some string' debe ser un número entre -2147483648 y 2147483647. Ejemplo: 9346"

  which is translated to: "j_idt8:age: 'some string' must be a number between -2147483648 and 2147483647. Example: 9346".

Is there anything I'm missing? Is there any way to implement a simple message warning? or is there anyway to customize the default message of: "j_idt8:age: 'some string' debe ser un número entre -2147483648 y 2147483647. Ejemplo: 9346"?

These are some code excerpt, in case you ask for them:

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <description>JSF will interpret empty strings submitted values as null</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

user Bean:

```
@NotNull(message = "Please enter your age")
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9][0-9]", message = "Age must be numeric")
@Max(99)
@Min(18)
private Integer age;
```

Facelets:

```
<h:form>
    Enter your age:<br/>
    <h:inputText id="age" value="#{user.age}">
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="ageMessage" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:message id="ageMessage" for="age" /><br/>

    <h:commandButton value="Insert" action="#{user.showChoice}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're facing a conversion error, not a validation error. The problem manifests long before the validation can ever take place. It's the builtin JSF `String`-`Integer` conversion which failed. Note that the `@Pattern` makes no sense on an `Integer` property. You cannot set it with an arbitrary `String` value.

If you change the property to be a `String`, then you'll see the "expected" results. But keeping it `Integer` is of course better if it should really represent a number. You can finetune the JSF converter message by the `converterMessage` attribute, or by supplying a custom `Converter` implementation, or by overriding the default message bundle file in `<message-bundle>`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'll look for overriding the default message bundle.

Comment: It's the key `javax.faces.converter.IntegerConverter.INTEGER_detail`. You can find them all in chapter 2.5.2.4 of JSF2 spec. You can find all default values in the `javax.faces.Messages` bundle of the JSF API JAR file.